# Как в angularjs писать код на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть такая директива

```
    app.directive('curSor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div class="cursor-child"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            const win = angular.element(window);
            const elem = angular.element(element);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            win.on('click', ()=>{
                elem.children().addClass('cursor-child-active');
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    elem.children().removeClass('cursor-child-active');
                },200);
            });
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            win.on('mousemove', function(e){
                elem.css({
                    "top":e.pageY  - "2" +"px",
                    "left":e.pageX  - "2" +"px"
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Когда писал этот пример, у меня не получилось написать его на чистом `JS`.

К примеру

```js
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('win');
})
```

Angularjs выдает ошибку, что мол такой функции `addEventListener`  не существует.

Вопросы...

Можно ли в `AnguarJS` писать код на чистом `JS`?

И стоит ли это вообще делать?

> P.S. Нет желание глубоко изучать JQ...)))

Нерабочий пример...

```js
const app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('curSor', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<div class="cursor-child">CursorChild</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      const win = angular.element(window);
      const elem = angular.element(element);
      //elem.children().classList.add('cursor-child-active');
      win.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('win');
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <cur-sor></cur-sor>
</body>

</html>
```

Помогите понять до конца ***Angularjs*** как верно и грамотно на нем писать?  Осознаю, что последний вопрос слишком глобальный...

Comment: любой код в angularjs является чистым JS.

Comment: @Grundy, но почему тогда для  него не существует `addEventListener`, перед тем как задать вопрос, у меня примеров было столько, что  наверное тут бы не поместилось...  Помимо `addEventListener` у меня не срабатывало  изменение стилей на чистом ***js*** , к примеру `element.style.top......`

Comment: нужен конкретный пример кода демонстрирующий ошибку. То что ты привел в вопросе - прекрасно работает

Comment: @Grundy, переписал вопрос, глянь последний пример... расскоментируй  строку в коде...

Comment: `angular.element` - возвращает jQuery объект, логично что в нем нет метода из обычного элемента

Comment: с children еще проще - это коллекция, у коллекции в принципе нет свойства classList, даже у какого-нибудь NodeList - нужно выбирать конкретный элемент

Comment: @Grundy, на счет коллекции элементов понял, промашка вышла... Забыл про индекс или цикл...  ***`angular.element - возвращает jQuery объект, логично что в нем нет метода из обычного элемента`***, получается, что придется писать на `JQ`?  Будь другом покажи конкретный пример на моем рабочем примере, как его переписать на чистом JS, или это не возможно...???

Comment: просто убери вызов angular.element

Comment: @Grundy, я тебя понял... Ну вот щас, спрашивать, что и почему у мне не получалось конечно же глупо ( ***ты не видел моих попыток***). Но вопрос такой -  писать код на чистом `js`, это верное решение? У меня была попытка  как в ответе у ***Qwertiy*** `window.addEventListener('click', () => {console.log('Что-то')}` и...  Ну вот поверь не сработало... Плюс забыл про цикл и индекс элемента, тут меня `JQ` немного с толку сбил... Вот щас переписал все тут для пробы в сниппете и все заработало....

Comment: @Air, там jQuery только если ты его сам подключил, причём до ангуляра. Иначе JQLite.

Comment: @Qwertiy, никогда не обращал внимание на `Lite` в слове `JQLite`  и при изучении ***(в уроках)*** не было ни слово про это, но как я понял щас это некая отдельная библиотека на основе `JQ`  именно для `AngularJS`? Я правильно понимаю? И все методы и функции  `AngularJS` - `ng-click, ng-class...` - это и есть `JQLite`?

Comment: @Air, нет. На оба вопроса. Она не на основе jquery, а его урезанная версия, которая кучу возможностей jquery не поддерживает. И она не для ангуляра, а сама по себе, посто ангуляр её использует в случае, если не нашёл нормального подключенного jquery. Поэтому если jquery есть, его надо подключать до ангуляра. А ангулярные директивы к нему вообще не имеют отношения.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Благодарю, все встало на свои места...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> win.addEventListener('click', () => {
> ```

```
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
```

```
win.on('click', () => {
```

Comment: Ну вот, опять минусатор набрёл ((

Comment: Qwertiy, я тоже...)))  Но если честно твой ответ не понял... У меня вроде так как у тебя...

Comment: @Air, в цитате - твой код. Потом два альтернативных варианта правильного.

Comment: Qwertiy, я тя понял. Вот щас почему-то  сработало.... Прочитай мой последний коммент под вопросом